# 8 adjacent squares

Tags: code-golf

List the coordinates of 8 squares adjacent to `(0, 0)` in a 2d grid. Namely,

`[(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(0,-1)]`

Order does not matter. The goal is to store the points into a list. Shortest answer wins.

Comment: Formatted exactly like the string in your question, or listed in the native/natural format for your language?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, listed in natural format.

Comment: Can you just clarify if the `(0, 0)` has to be omitted from the output?

Comment: @Gareth, yes, it has to be omitted. It would be 9 squares with `(0,0)`, after all.

Comment: Does the list need to be output to stdout, or is simply storing it in a list/array sufficient?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, store only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## J - 12 char

The most natural representation of a list of pairs is a list of boxes containing each pair.

```
   }.4|.,{;~i:1
+---+----+---+---+-----+----+----+----+
|0 1|1 _1|1 0|1 1|_1 _1|_1 0|_1 1|0 _1|
+---+----+---+---+-----+----+----+----+
```

The magic happens in `{`, called *Catalogue*. It is essentially a generalized Cartesian product. The `}.4|.` part is for removing the `0 0` pair.

Answer (score 15):

### Bash + grep  35

```
eval echo\ {-1..1},{-1..1}\;|grep 1
```

I know this doesn't beat the other bash answer but someone had to think of `grep`

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby <s>29</s> <s>28</s> 26

```
(a=-1,1,0).product(a)[0,8]
```

#### Bonus solution:

Ruby has many nice builtin array operators, but some of them have ridiculously long names.

```
[*[-1,1,0].repeated_permutation(2)].take 8
```

Comment: Doesn't this include the `0,0`?

Comment: You don't actually need the square brackets in your first answer.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma + Gareth Yup. So do other answers here I suspect. Fixed it anyways.

Comment: I FIXED IT!!!! give a poor guy a little breathing room before downvoting, eh?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma :P

Comment: You can go further: `(a=-1,1,0).product(a)[0,8]` is 26 chars.

Comment: @algorithmshark you're right -- thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## Python <strike>43</strike> 32

```
l=zip([1,-1,0]*3,[-1,1]*3+[0]*2)
```

Inspired by @primo

Comment: I don't think this is 43 bytes anymore :)

Comment: It looks like 43 characters to me - am I missing something? Oh wow, that solution above is sweet.

Comment: @issacg I had miscounted earlier, my mistake. Nice improvement, though.

Comment: I like it. Nice improvement on my 40.

Answer (score 7):

### GolfScript (17 chars)

```
9,4-{[.3/(\3%(]}%
```

Since the question calls for the points to be "listed in natural format", this leaves an array on the stack. To pretty-print it, append `p`, as in the [online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OSw0LXtbLjMvKFwzJShdfSUKcA%3D%3D).

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell 32

```
c=[0,1,-1]
_:l=[(a,b)|a<-c,b<-c]
```

The list is l (L).

Comment: You could do `_:l=(,)<$>c<*>c` to save 6 characters, although it requires `import Control.Applicative`.

Comment: Yeah, having free import statements would be pretty cool. It'd be interesting to specify free imports on a challenge, and see what sort of different responses you'ld get.

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, 1093 characters.

```
++++++++[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++>+++++++++++++>++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>>>+++.---<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>.<<<<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<>>>>>+.-<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<<<<<<<.
```

## EDIT 209 characters

```
++++++++++[>+++++++++>++++>+++++>++++<<<<-]>+.>.>-.>++++.<.<+.>>.<<-.>.>.<-.<+.>>.<<-.>+.>.+.-<.<+.>>.<<-.>-.>.<+.<+.>>.<<-.>-.>.+.<+.<+.>>-.<<-.>>+.<.>-.<.<+.>>.<<-.>>+.<.>-.<-.<+.>>.<<-.>>+.<+.>-.+.<.<+.<++.
```

Original by Benjamin - i gave it another shot as well and got to 209 characters as well.

Comment: Someday, Brainfuck will win a code-golf contest !

Comment: @Michael : it did, once: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/write-a-program-that-uses-all-printable-non-alphanumeric-ascii-symbols/8926#8926

Comment: My solution is 5 times more concise :) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25666/20279

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 43 bytes

```perl
for$x(-1..1){$x|$_&&push@r,[$x,$_]for-1..1}
```

The result is stored in array `@r`. Explicitly it can be defined with 58 bytes:

```perl
@r=([-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1])
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 16 characters

```
   }.4|.,<@,"0/~i:1
```

Usage:

```
   }.4|.,<@,"0/~i:1
┌───┬────┬───┬───┬─────┬────┬────┬────┐
│0 1│1 _1│1 0│1 1│_1 _1│_1 0│_1 1│0 _1│
└───┴────┴───┴───┴─────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

Pretty ugly - especially dropping the `(0, 0)`. There's probably a better way.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 23

```
Most@Tuples[{-1,1,0},2]
(*
{{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}
*)
```

Comment: Cheeky. :) Very nice idea! I think precedence rules should allow you to replace `Tuples[{...},2]` with `{...}~Tuples~2` to save another byte.

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks. That byte is lost afterwards when trying to apply `Most[]` (or I can't find a way around it). BTW I never  saw you around http://mathematica.stackexchange.com  Any particular reason?

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: Ah, I thought `~..~` had higher precedence than `@`. I think that means I can save a byte in quite a few of my mathematica-answers :D. No particular reason why I haven't been around mathematica stackexchange, but I haven't used other SE sites other than SO much until recently. And I don't really consider myself an expert in Mathematica to be answering interesting questions. And I also don't use it for more than some casual stuff like here in code golf and the odd physics problem.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma `Tuples[{a,b,c ...}, n]` generates all possible lists of length `n` containing `{a,b,c ...}` as elements. Then `Most[]` discards the last one (which is `{0,0}` )

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck, <s>217</s> 209 characters.

Only a bit worse than Java!
5x less than the other BF solution.

```
++++++++++[>+++++++++>++++>+++++>++++<<<<-]>+.>.>-.>++++.+.<.<+.>>-.<<-.>.>.<-.<+.>>.<<-.>+.>.<.<+.>>.<<-.>-.>.<+.<+.>>.<<-.>>+.<.>-.<.<+.>>.<<-.>>+.<.>-.<-.<+.>>.<<-.>>+.<+.>-.+.<.<+.>>-.<<-.>-.>.+.<+.<+.<++.
```

Comment: You mean 1/5th of the other solution :D But i accept your challlenge. Allthough i think i can not get it any smaller than this.

Comment: Hah.. I gave it a shot as well and came to the same amount of characters... Coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 44 characters

```
Outer[List,d=Range@3-2,d]~Flatten~1~Drop~{5}
```

Well. Generates all 9 coordinates, flattens the list and drops the centre.

Comment: Very nice use of common functions, Outer and Range, but they should not return the point {0,0}.

Comment: @m.buettner Good. Thanks.  +1

Answer (score 3):

## Python 50:

```
l=[(a,b)for a in[1,0,-1]for b in[1,0,-1]];l.pop(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 25 characters

Storing the list of coordinates as a bash array `a`:

```
a=({-1..1},{-1..1});a[4]=
```

Output:

```
$ a=({-1..1},{-1..1});a[4]=
$ echo ${a[@]}
-1,-1 -1,0 -1,1 0,-1 0,1 1,-1 1,0 1,1
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## F# - <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```
[for i in 0..7->i*2/5-1,(i*5/4)%3-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 56

```
r=range(-1,2);list({(i,j) for i in r for j in r}-{(0,0)})
```

Improved to

```
r=[-1,0,1];list({(i,j) for i in r for j in r}-{(0,0)})
```

with storage of the variable

```
r=[-1,0,1];l=list({(i,j) for i in r for j in r}-{(0,0)})
```

Comment: `r=[-1,0,1]` is shorter!

Comment: You're right- nice one

Comment: Um, you need to `print` it.

Comment: Only storing is needed according to the instructions, so perhaps its necessary to add `l=` before `list` at a price of 2 chars

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 60

Let's do this an interesting way. Hint: "2" is ASCII 50.

```
char x[]="11123332",y[8],i;for(i=8;i--;)y[(i+2)%8]=x[i]-=50;
```

Comment: Can you do `char *x="11123332"` to save a char?

Comment: or just `auto x="11123332"` to save another

Comment: @DigitalTrauma you can, but only once the array has been declared, otherwise it throws an exception. Eliminating declarations my code becomes `char*x="11123332";for(i=8;i--;)y[(i+2)%8]=x[i]-=50;` saving 8 bytes. You have to include the type specifier `char` so it knows what to store in *x.

Comment: or `char*x="11123332"` if you're not so comfortable with `auto`.

Comment: You can save another byte with `i=8;while(i--)` I believe. Combine with `char*x=` and you're looking at only 57 bytes.

Comment: `(i+2)%8` -> `i+2&7`

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6: 27 characters

Most simply:

```
$/=(-1..1 X -1..1)[^4,5..*]
```

Get the permutations of -1, 0, and 1 with itself, and hard-code skipping (0, 0). But that's no fun! I prefer things to be more complex: (50 characters)

```
$/=map {[.re,.im]},grep *.abs>0,(-1..1 X+ -i,0i,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 37 bytes

```
a=[(i*2/5-1,-i%3-1)for i in range(8)]
```

An alternative at 40:

```
a=zip([0,1,-1]*3,[0]*3+[1]*3+[-1]*3)[1:]
```

And a 42 that's also interesting:

```
a=0,1,-1;a=zip(sum(zip(a,a,a),()),a*3)[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java <strike>207</strike> 204

Way too much, I know, but its the best I could do right now...
I might think of something better...

```
class A{public static void main(String...a){int[][] l=new int[8][2];for(int x=-1,y,i=0;x<2;x++){for(y=-1;y<2;y++){if(x!=0||y!=0){l[i][0]=x;l[i][1]=y;System.out.print("("+l[i][0]+","+l[i][1]+")");i++;}}}}}
```

Sensibly:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String...a) {
        int[][] l = new int[8][2];
        for (int x = -1, y, i = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            for (y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                if (x != 0 || y != 0) {
                    l[i][0] = x;
                    l[i][1] = y;
                    System.out.print("("+l[i][0]+","+l[i][1]+")");
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `main(String[] args)` -> `main(String...s)` Saves 3 characters.

Comment: I bet `String[]a` is better than `String...a`

Answer (score 1):

## APL (13 characters)

```
1↓,∘.,⍨0 1 ¯1
```

Explanation:

```
1↓           ⍝ Drop the first element of
  ,          ⍝ an array that comes from the matrix formed by
   ∘.,⍨      ⍝ concatenating each element with every other element
       0 1 ¯1⍝ in this array [0,1,-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PYG (27):

```
P(*ItPr((-1,0,1),repeat=2))
```

Nothing all that special, really.

In regular python:

```
from itertools import product
for i in product((-1,0,1),repeat=2): print i
```

Comment: This prints `(0, 0)`. I think this is not supposed to be included

Comment: The OP has clarified (0,0) should not be included.  Let me know when you fix this and I'll remove my downvote :)

Comment: What is this "PYG", you speak of? (Presumably not a Pig Latin program or yet another package manager.)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 73

```
main(i){for(i=0;i<9;i++)if(i-4)printf("%s(%d,%d)",i?",":"",i%3-1,i/3-1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica: 41

This works most of the time ;)

```
Union[RandomInteger[2,{99,2}]-1]~Drop~{5}
```

Equivalently:

```
Drop[Union@RandomInteger[2,{99,2}]-1,{5}]
```

Comment: In the first case you can lose another character, by using infix notation for `RandomInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab: 53

Similar to my other answer:

```
unique(round(2*rand(99,2))-1,'rows');ans([1:4,6:9],:)
```

I couldn't index on the output of unique directly, and I couldn't find a way around that...

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell 97

Too much for Haskell and definitely not as good as the other Haskell answer, but here's a different, albeit sucky, approach:

```
take 8 (zip (replicate 3 (-1) ++ replicate 3 1 ++ replicate 3 0) (concat (replicate 3 [-1,1,0])))
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 56

Self-explanatory.

```
def x=List(-1,0,1);for{i<-x;j<-x;if i!=0|j!=0}yield(i,j)
```

Ungolfed:

```
def x=List(-1,0,1)
for{
  i <- x
  j <- x
  if i!=0 | j!=0
} yield(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 42 characters:

```
@r=map[split","],grep/1/,glob"{-1,0,1},"x2
```

Uses the shell-like glob functionality to generate the list of strings `("-1,-1","-1,0","-1,1","0,-1","0,0","0,1","1,-1","1,0","1,1")`, discards strings that don't contain the character `"1"` (i.e. drop `"0,0"`), then splits the strings on comma to get the desired data structure.

### 41 characters:

```
@r=map[split x],grep/1/,glob"{-1,0,1}x"x2
```

abuses barewords: the strings are `("-1x-1","-1x0"`, etc.`)` and the split is done on the letter `x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES5) 52 bytes

```javascript
[[n=-1,n],[n,0],[n,1],[0,n],[0,1],[1,n],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

---

## Javascript (ES5) (*algorithmic*) 57 bytes

```javascript
for(a=-2,x=[];++a<2;)for(b=-2;++b<2;)a|b&&x.push([a,b]);x
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fortran: <s>101</s> 96

Fortran supports [complex variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), so we just store the 8 values as a set of complex numbers and get ourselves a list of tuples.

```
complex x(8);x=reshape([(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(0,-1)],[8]);print*,x;end
```

Printing this to look nice might be a pain in the butt because printing the `real` and `aimag` [components](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.5/g77/REAL_0028_0029-and-AIMAG_0028_0029-of-Complex.html) adds a lot of bytes. But we can deal with floats.

---

Old answer:

```
complex x(8);k=1;do i=-1,1;do j=-1,1;if((j==0).and.(i==0))cycle;x(k)=cmplx(i,j);k=k+1;enddo;enddo;end
```

This abuses implicit typing (as usual).

Answer (score 0):

## SQL 109 (that far)

```
create table a(x int);insert into a values(-1),(0),(1);select a.x,b.x y from a,a b where not(a.x=0 and b.x=0)
```

if you want to retest it, you can prepend `drop table if exists a;`

Answer (score 0):

**C#** 140 chars

Shorter version:

```
List<string> a=new List<string>();for(int i=0,m=-1;i<3;i++,m++){for(int j=0,n=-1;j<3;j++,n++){if(m==0 && n==0)continue;array.Add(m+","+n);}}
```

Easy to read version:

```
List<string> array = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0, m = -1; i < 3; i++, m++)
{
    for(int j = 0, n = -1; j < 3; j++, n++)
    {
         if (m == 0 && n == 0) continue;
         array.Add(m + "," + n);
    }
}
```