# Orthodiagonal steps

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, matrix

It's a common problem to navigate in a 2D matrix. We've seen it many times and will see again. So let's help future us and develop the shortest solutions to generate all eight possible steps in a 2D matrix.

### Challenge

Your code must output the following 8 pairs of -1,0,1 in any order:

```
(0,1)
(0,-1)
(1,0)
(-1,0)
(1,1)
(1,-1)
(-1,1)
(-1,-1)
```

### Rules

1. There is no input.
2. Output order is not relevant
3. Output is flexible. Pairs of numbers just need to be distinguishable
4. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: I'm 100% sure that this is a duplicate, but I'm having trouble coming up with the right search terms to find the old challenge...

Comment: @MartinEnder I was 99% sure about that too, but didn't find any either. So I've put it in sandbox for a few days, but noone commented about duplicate.

Comment: I also remember there being an old challenge that was either exactly this or this in large part.

Comment: Because of the flexible output, there turns out to be an interesting Kolmogorov complexity flavour to this one. Some languages will find it harder than to do better than just hard coding the output. Should this tag be added?

Comment: May we output a list of complex numbers, `[0+i,0-i,1,-1,1+i`…?

Comment: @Adám I believe, there would be interesting answers with complex numbers, and I want to allow it, but lots of people already answered with pairs of numbers, as stated in question, so I'd say, that it would be discouraging to them, so no.

Comment: @ngm Hardcoding answer is rather boring solution, but it is still a solution, no doubt. Though I don't want to add this tag to encourage such solutions.

Comment: @DeadPossum May we use `J` to separate the coordinates instead of `,` e.g. `0J1` instead of `(0,1)`?

Comment: @Adám Yes, use anything while pairs of numbers are distinguishable

Comment: @DeadPossum APL represents `0+1i` as `0J1`.

Comment: @Adám But what about `(1 + 0i)` ?

Comment: @DeadPossum Differs between APL systems. Maybe some do display an imaginary part on all members of a list if at least one member has an imaginary part. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Adám Well, if both parts are displayed explicitly, it'll borderline-ish pass as valid answer

Comment: @DeadPossum Wouldn't that be unfair to other languages which happen to have a different display format for complex numbers? (Read: allow returning a list of complex numbers!)

Comment: @Adám True. No complex numbers. No hesitations.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [8 adjacent squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25493/20080), one of the first code golfs I ever did.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot I got a hammer two days ago... I voted (and accidentally hammered) close the other one as a dupe of this one. Feel free to undo it, but I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Can I use input command `.i` in Pxem, as it treats EOF as -1?

Answer (score 20):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 24 bytes

```matlab
dec2base([0:3,5:8],3)-49
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JTXZKCmxOFUj2sDKWMfUyiJWx1hT18Ty/38A)

I haven't seen this approach yet.

Creates a list of integers `[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, and converts it to ternary, returning a character array:

```matlab
00
01
02
10
12
20
21
22
```

Subtracting `49` (ASCII-value for `1`) from all characters gives a numeric array:

```matlab
-1  -1
-1   0
-1   1
 0  -1
 0   1
 1  -1
 1   0
 1   1
```

Answer (score 9):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 36

```bash
a=({0,-1,1},{0,-1,1})
echo ${a[@]:1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9FWo9pAR9dQx7BWB8bQ5EpNzshXUKlOjHaItTKs/f8fAA)

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) with Sed, 35

```bash
printf %s\\n {-1..1},{-1..1}|sed 5d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1OCYmT6Fa11BPz7BWB0rXFKemKJim/P8PAA)

Comment: [Alternatively](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@h2kBH11DHsFYHxqhJLi1R0E0z0lXQTYlR@P8fAA "Bash – Try It Online") using `cut` for 36 bytes as well.

Comment: 33 bytes for bash+sed (despite how boring it is), [`echo {-1..1},{-1..1}|sed s/0,0.//`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hWtdQT8@wVgdK1xSnpigU6xvoGOjp6///DwA)

Comment: `printf %s\\n {-1..1},{-1..1}|grep 1` is also 35.

Answer (score 9):

## T-SQL, <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```sql
SELECT-1n INTO t;INSERT t VALUES(0),(1)SELECT*FROM t,t z WHERE t.n<>0OR z.n<>0
```

Creates a (permanent) table **t** containing `(-1,0,1)`, and performs a self-join with a `WHERE` clause that excludes the `0,0` row. The table **t** is not cleaned up by my code, you must drop it yourself.

Sadly nearly twice as long as the boring solution (**44 bytes**), since SQL allows returns in strings:

```sql
PRINT'0,1
0,-1
1,0
-1,0
1,1
1,-1
-1,1
-1,-1'
```

Comment: I don't know T-SQL so well: can you use just `WHERE t.n OR z.n`? (You can in some but not all SQL dialects.)

Comment: @msh210 Good idea, I tried it but it doesn't seem to work on MS SQL Server. I get the error: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected`

Comment: You can remove the spaces around the *

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

Credits to @JDoe for saving two more bytes with a direct approach:

```r
paste(-1:1,-3:5%/%3)[-5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyCxuCRVQ9fQylBH19jKVFVf1VgzWtc09v9/AA)

The original asnwer:

```r
outer(-1:1,-1:1,paste)[-5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7@0JLVIQ9fQylAHTBQkFpekakbrmsb@/w8A)

Or for 27 bytes

```r
sapply(-1:1,paste,-1:1)[-5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzixoCCnUkPX0MpQpyCxuCRVB8TUjNY1jf3/HwA)

Or for 34 bytes with factors:

```r
(gl(3,3,,-1:1):gl(3,1,9,-1:1))[-5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XyM9R8NYx1hHR9fQylDTCswz1LGEcDWjdU1j//8HAA)

This last solution might be the golfiest if the output could be from 1 to 3 rather than from -1 to 1.

See [the other R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164763/80010) for alternate solutions with `expand.grid` or with `cbind`.

Comment: huh, nice use of the flexible output format!

Comment: This one is better than mine because of how ultimately useless it is :)

Comment: @Giuseppe Originally I tried `c` which did not make sense inside a matrix so I switched to `paste` and the original output format...

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyCxuCRVQ9fQylBH19jKVFVf1VgzWtc09v9/AA "R – Try It Online") with `paste`

Comment: @J.Doe you rock!

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
3p_2ẸƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@4IN7o4a4dx9r//wcA)

My first ever Jelly answer! Much thanks to Dennis for the final piece of the puzzle.

Now, let's see if I can explain it ... lol.

```
3p_2ẸƇ   Main program, takes no input.
3p       Product with Range 3, yields [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,2], ...]
  _2     Decrement twice, vectorizes, yields [[-1,-1], [-1,0], [-1,1], [0,-1], ...]
    ẸƇ   Comb, removes those that contain only falsey values, the [0,0]
         Implicit output
```

*-1 byte thanks to Erik; -1 byte thanks to Mr Xcoder and Dennis*

Comment: Alterate answer based on this approach: `3p3_2ẸƇ`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You can drop the second `3`.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, indeed. In this case, Adm can update with the 6-byter :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
i=9;exec"print-i%3-1,i/5;i-=2;"*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0jq1IjVZqaAoM69EN1PVWNdQJ1Pf1DpT19bIWknL4v9/AA)

Dennis saved <s>3</s> 5 bytes, wow. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
_:l=mapM(:[1,-1])[0,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P94qxzY3scBXwyraUEfXMFYz2kDHIPZ/bmJmnm1BUWZeiULO/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

*Laikoni saved 1 byte.*

Comment: `_:l=mapM(:[1,-1])[0,0]` saves a byte. (Taken from [isaacg's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25544/56433) to the earlier challenge).

Comment: @Laikoni So I had considered that and thought that would make it a snippet (as many answers to the old challenge were). But combining [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12924/20260) with the rule that functions can be defined indirectly, so this seems to be OK. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-Q`, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

I'm sure there's a shorter way, but I liked this approach.

```js
##ü80ì3 mÉ ò
##ü80        // Take 14425280
     ì3      // and turn it into an array of base-3 numbers.
        mÉ   // Subtract one from each digit
           ò // and then split them pairwise.
```

Shaved off two bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy).

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=I5Aj/Dgw7DMgbckg8g==&input=LVE=)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```
9ó8_ìJõ é)Å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3/LwZov4w2u8Dm9VOLxS83Dr//@6QQA) Uses `-R` flag to put each item on its own line.

#### Explanation

```
9ó8_ìJõ é)Å
9ó8             Create the range [9, 9+8). [9, 10, ..., 16]
   _            Map each item in this range through this function:
     Jõ é)        Generate the range [-1...1] and rotate to get [1, -1, 0].
    ì             Convert the item to an array of base-3 digits,
                  mapping [0,1,2] to [1,-1,0]. [[-1, 1, 1], [-1, 1,-1], [-1, 1, 0],
                                                [-1,-1, 1], [-1,-1,-1], [-1,-1, 0],
                                                [-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0,-1]]
          Å       Remove the first item (gets rid of the leading -1).
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>83</s> 42 bytes

```java
v->"1,1 1,0 1,-1 0,1 0,-1 -1,1 -1,0 -1,-1"
```

-41 bytes thanks to *@AdmBorkBork* by hard-coding..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU5BCoMwELz3FYunCEbMWdof1IvQS@lhG22JjVHMGijFt6cbFHZgd4aZnQEDyqH7RG3Re7iicb8TgHHULy/UPTTpBGhpMe4NWtwm00HIa2Y3Bo8nJKOhAQdniEFeMlUoUEXFkAqqIoEXmWiZeJmELNa7f16flv1HTEj5I9cQ@8v7A/OjwtdTP5bTSuXMCglXauFWa/OjzRb/)

---

Non hard-coded version as reference (**<s>83</s> <s>72</s> <s>70</s> 68 bytes**):

```java
v->{for(int i=9;i-->1;)System.out.println(~i%3+1+","+(~(i/3)%3+1));}
```

-11 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-2 bytes creating a port of [*@ETHproductions*'s JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164797/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BCoMwDIbve4owGLS4OsTTKPoG8yLsMnboqo66WsVWYYi@ehenkBD@hPz/V4tRsLr4eKmFtXATykwHAGVc2VdClpCtEmBsVQGS3NcxUo67GRvLOuGUhAwMJOBHlk5V2xP8B5VcuWIsjTjNv9aVTdgOLux6vGlDFnWKgyg4no8BWYi6xHTVlPLZ8825G14anfeAP0CDeCR3aPF@PAXd0EwoiRm03qlm/wM)

Comment: Non-hardcoded answer in 72 bytes: `v->{for(int i=9;i-->0;)if(i!=4)System.out.println((i/3-1)+","+(i%3-1));}`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks, added (and golfed by 2 more bytes).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 23 bytes

```perl6
{(1,-1,0 X 1,-1,0)[^8]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNQR9dQx0AhQgHC0IyOs4it/V@cWKmQpqFp/R8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
2Ý<ãʒĀZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6PBcm8OLT0060hD1/z8A)

**Explanation**

```
2Ý<     # Range of 2 decremented, yields [-1, 0, 1]
   ã    # Cartesian product of the list with itself
    ʒ   # Filter by ...
     ĀZ # Maximum of the truthified values, yields 0 only if both values are 0.
```

-1 byte thanks to Emigna !

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it. Had the same start (`2Ý<ã`), but was figuring out how to remove the middle element of the list of pairs.. Hadn't thought about sort by absolute value and removing the first.. +1 from me.

Comment: Use `ʒĀZ` to save 1

Comment: @Emigna Thanks for making me understand the difference between the regular and the 05AB1IE version of the truthified command :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

There are a lot of different ways (the tricky/costly part is getting rid of `[0,0]`), <s>7 bytes is the shortest I could come up</s> thanks to [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo?tab=profile) for pointing out to use decimal conversion (`d`) as a filter:

```
fdπ2ṡ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py3lfIPRw50LDf//BwA)

#### Explanation

```
fdπ2ṡ1  -- constant function (expects no arguments)
    ṡ1  -- symmetric range [-n..n]: [-1,0,1]
  π2    -- cartesian power of 2: [[-1,-1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[-1,1],[0,0],[1,-1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
f       -- filter only elements that are truthy when
 d      -- | decimal conversion (interpret as polynomial and evaluate at x=10)
        -- : [[-1,-1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

---

### Alternative, 7 bytes

```
tπ2ṙ1ṡ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v@R8g9HDnTMNH@5caPj/PwA)

#### Explanation

```
tπ2ṙ1ṡ1  -- constant function (expects no arguments)
     ṡ1  -- symmetric range [-n..n]: [-1,0,1]
   ṙ1    -- rotate by 1: [0,1,-1]
 π2      -- cartesian power of 2: [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[1,1],[-1,0],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,-1]]
t        -- tail: [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[1,1],[-1,0],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,-1]]
```

Comment: Another 7 byte alternative [`tπ2↑3İZ`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v@R8g9GjtonGRzZE/f8PAA).

Comment: You can save one byte by filtering the lists based on their decimal conversion [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py3lfIPRw50LDf//BwA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
9:q4X-3YA49-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39Kq0CRC1zjS0cRS9/9/AA)

Because it's MATL month, here's a MATL port of @Stewie's Octave answer. The sequence [0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8] is generated as the set difference between [0 ... 8] and 4.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
expand.grid(-1:1,-1:1)[-5,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7WiIDEvRS@9KDNFQ9fQylAHRGhG65rqxP7/DwA)

30 and 35 bytes:

```r
cbind(-1:1,rep(-1:1,e=3))[-5,]
expand.grid(rep(list(-1:1),2))[-5,]
```

Comment: Some funky looking output, I like it :D Good job

Comment: `expand.grid(-1:1,-1:1)[-5,]` is 27 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```hs
tail.mapM id$[0,1,-1]<$"ao"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvyQxM0cvN7HAVyEzRSXaQMdQR9cw1kZFKTFf6X9uYmaebUFRZl6JQtr/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6)

Two alternate methods, both longer than hardcoding.

### 49 bytes

```javascript
_=>[...'11202200'].map((n,i,a)=>[~-n,~-a[i+3&7]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i5aT09P3dDQyMDIyMBAPVYvN7FAQyNPJ1MnURMoWaebp1OnmxidqW2sZh4bq/k/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTUNT8z8A)

### 51 bytes

```javascript
f=(n=1679887e3)=>n?[n%4-1,~-(n/4%4)]+' '+f(n>>4):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjz9bQzNzSwsI81VjT1i7PPjpP1UTXUKdOVyNP30TVRDNWW11BXTtNI8/OzkTTSl39f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
echo}.,{;~0 1 _1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I79WT6faus5AwVAh3vD/fwA)

Comment: Why minus is displayed as underscore in TIO?

Comment: 18 bytes alternative: `echo }.>,{;~0 1 _1`
[TIO](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1@hVs9Op9q6zkDBUCHe8P9/AA)

Comment: @Dead Possum Negative numbers are displayed with an underscore in J

Comment: Yes, 17 :)  `echo}.>,{;~0 1 _1`

Comment: Is `echo` needed?

Comment: agree with @cole, it seems like snippets should be allowed on "output only" challenges in J, but not totally clear on the rules

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 41 bytes

```powershell
(1..-1|%{$i=$_;1..-1|%{"$i,$_"}})-ne'0,0'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT0/XsEa1WiXTViXeGsZTUsnUUYlXqq3V1M1LVTfQMVD//x8A)

Double-for loop over the range `1..-1`, with a `-n`ot`e`quals at the end to pull out the extraneous `0,0` entry. They're each individually left on the pipeline and implicit `Write-output` at program completion gives us newlines for free.

---

Sadly, just the barebones string output is two bytes shorter:

```powershell
'1,1
1,0
1,-1
0,1
0,-1
-1,1
-1,0
-1,-1'
```

But that's boring.

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 bytes

```perl
map/1/&&say,<{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1}>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUDfUF9NrTixUsemWtdQx0DHsFYHxrD7//9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDAA)

Comment: Would `-1..1` work in the glob?

Comment: @msh210 [Unfortunately not...](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/fUF9NrTixUiEtv8hGqVrXUE/PsFYBSivZ/f//L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") I did experiment with it, and it works in `bash`, but not in Perl :(

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 13 bytes

```
3,:(2m*{2b},`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31jHSsMoV6vaKKlWJ@H/fwA)

### Explanation

```
3,    e# Range [0,3):       [0 1 2]
:(    e# Decrement each:    [-1 0 1]
2m*   e# Cartesian square:  [[-1 -1] [-1 0] [-1 1] [0 -1] [0 0] [0 1] [1 -1] [1 0] [1 1]]
{     e# Filter by
 2b   e#   conversion to binary:
},    e#                    [[-1 -1] [-1 0] [-1 1] [0 -1] [0 1] [1 -1] [1 0] [1 1]]
`     e# Stringify:         "[[-1 -1] [-1 0] [-1 1] [0 -1] [0 1] [1 -1] [1 0] [1 1]]"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
n=6;exec'n+=~(n==2);print n/3,n%3-1;'*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WzDq1IjVZPU/btk4jz9bWSNO6oCgzr0QhT99YJ0/VWNfQWl3L4v9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
tail$(,)<$>t<*>t
t=[0,1,-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKIQ878kMTNHRUNH00bFrsRGy66Eq8Q22kDHUEfXMPb//3/JaTmJ6cX/dSOcAwIA)

The output is `[(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(-1,-1)]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 54 bytes

```fs
let f=Seq.where((<>)(0,0))(Seq.allPairs[-1..1][-1..1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Pye1RCHNNji1UK88I7UoVUPDxk5Tw0DHQFNTAySYmJMTkJhZVByta6inZxgLpTT/pynU2CmAFGSWpBYpaBQUZeaVpOUpKKk6Kmn@BwA)

44 bytes - thanks to Laikoni:

```fs
let f=Seq.tail(Seq.allPairs[0;-1;1][0;-1;1])
```

Comment: 44 bytes by having `(0,0)` be the first element and calling `Seq.tail`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Pye1RCHNNji1UK8kMTNHA8RIzMkJSMwsKo42sNY1tDaMhdGa/9MUauwUQEoyS1KLFDQKijLzStLyFJRUHZU0/wMA "F# (Mono) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 24 bytes

```
11#v91090~9~19~<
9.._@#,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/39BQuczS0MDSoM6yztCyzobLUk8v3kFZ5/9/AA)

I feel like this challenge is missing answers from 2D languages, even if most don't move diagonally. This outputs space separated numbers, each pair separated by tabs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
Ċ{ṡᵐ≜}ᶠb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9icmFjaHlsb2cy///EinvhuaHhtZDiiZx94bagYv///1o)

#### Explanation

```
Ċ           Couple: take a list of two elements [A,B]
 {   }ᶠ     Find all…
    ≜         …possible values of…
  ṡᵐ          …signs of A and B
       b    Behead: remove the first one which is [0,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 30 bytes

```bash
echo "
"{-1..1},{-1..1}|grep 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BiUupWtdQT8@wVgdK16QXpRYoGP7/DwA)

Prints a trailing space on each line but the last. (Thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) - this originally printed a leading space, but a trailing space is better as per their comment)

Comment: I guess you could print a trailing space on all but the last line as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
3:qq2Z^[]5Y(
```

[Try it at MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=3%3Aqq2Z%5E%5B%5D5Y%28&inputs=&version=20.9.1)

My first ever serious MATL answer! Thanks a lot to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo), [Sanchises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises) and [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem) for the help.

#### How it works

```
3:qq2Z^[]5Y( – Full program. Outputs to STDOUT.
3:           – Range 3. Push [1 2 3] to the stack.
  qq         – Decrement by 2. Yields [-1 0 1].
    2Z^      – Cartesian power of 2.
         5Y( – Replace the row at index 5 with...
       []    – An empty vector.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 77 bytes

```
@for %%x in (-1 0 1)do @for %%y in (-1 0 1)do @if not %%x%%y==00 echo %%x %%y
```

63 bytes if a nonstandard separator is allowed:

```
@for %%x in (-1/-1 -1/0 -1/1 0/-1 0/1 1/-1 1/0 1/1)do @echo %%x
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
;Ø+p`Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/68AztgoSHO7r@/wcA)

-1 thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
t^+U2_1 2
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%5E%2BU2_1+2&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
t^+U2_1 2
  +U2_1     [0, 1, -1]
 ^      2   Product with itself.
t           Exclude the first.
```

Equivalently, we could use `t*J+U2_1J`, but that's not any shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

```javascript
f=(n=8)=>n?[...f(n-1),[1+~n%3,1+~(n/3)%3]]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjz9ZC09Yuzz5aT08vTSNP11BTJ9pQuy5P1VgHSGnk6RtrqhrHxlpFx/5Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9cAq9bU/A8A)

Another alternative to hardcoding, still not as short though...

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
[J1T]ê à2 s1J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P9rLMCT28CqFwwuMFIoNvf7/1w0CAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
τÄêdD┘│çû╢
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e78e886444d9b38796b6&i=)

Explanation (unpacked):

```
1:r2|^{|af|u Full program
1:r          Push [-1, 0, 1]
   2|^       Join with self
   c|*        Alternative: copy and join
      {  f   Filter:
       |a      Any truthy (not 0)?
          |u Representation
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <strike>79</strike>, <strike>76</strike>, 73 Bytes

76 Bytes thanks to Dom Hastings

[Try it online (79 Bytes) using base 16](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe8/wosJ2MK0OZT0kQlIWjMJEre/bTPSx1nnVuaSSmPNvuEyO91mYPTIa94QPU2Fk7NzYox1QKiQgBlAcJJCGcNikXihQ6PTSip1PTa0/) (**Original answer**)

[Try it online (77 Bytes) using base 36](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEgjOaM0Lzu@uCAns0QjKbE4NT45P68stahEQ8nQojCtKDW3stBMScfYTMdEU8dYR4lLSVMn2tjWTl1HXcfI1k7XMFbTmuv/fwA)

[Try it online (73 Bytes) using base 36](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEgjOaM0Lzu@uCAns0QjKbE4NT45P68stahEQ8nQojCtKDW3stBMScfYTMdEU8dYR4lLSVMn2sjWTtdQR0lHKVbT@v9/AA)

**Tried to avoid any kind of loop**

```
<?=strtr(chunk_split(base_convert("18qfremyq6",36,4),3,"
"),[2=>-1,',']);
//as the starting index is 2, next will be 3, no need for 3=>','
```

**Output**

```
1,0
-1,0
1,1
1,-1
-1,1
-1,-1
0,1
0,-1
```

**Explanation**

Basically <strike>`"72c75eb6e34e"`</strike> `18qfremyq6` is the base <strike>16</strike> 36 representation of a base 4 number `130230131132231232031032`, every `3` represents a `","` and `2` a `-1`

Chunk split, adds a line break every 3 characters.

**Shorter with an output without the comma, 79 Bytes**

```
<?=strtr(chunk_split(base_convert("10fcb5c",16,3),2,"
"),[2=>-1]);
```

**Output**

```
10
-10
11
1-1
-11
-1-1
01
0-1
```

Comment: or [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fUMeASxdEGOoYArGuIYgHJoBMAx0QBjK4/v8HAA) can be done with 37 bytes.

Comment: Yeah... I did think hard-coding would be smaller, but programatically is more interesting, right? :)

Comment: of couse, far more interesting :-D

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

```
3…(¦:×ỵ⁈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3/hRwzKNQ8usDk9/uHvro8aO//8B)

This generates the list in this order:

```
[[-1 -1] [-1 0] [-1 1] [0 -1] [0 1] [1 -1] [1 0] [1 1]]
```

#### Explanation

```
3…(¦:×ỵ⁈ – Full program. Outputs to STDOUT.
3…       – Push [0 1 2] to the stack.
  (¦     – Decrement each; yields [-1 0 1].
    :    – Duplicate.
     ×   – Cartesian product.
       ⁈ – Filter-reject those that:
      ỵ  – Have no truthy element.
```

An alternative to this would be [`3…(¦2*ỵ⁈`](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3/hRwzKNQ8uMtB7u3vqoseP/fwA).

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

4 Japt solutions to one challenge; that has to be a first :)

```
Jõ ï fd
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=SvUg7yBmZA==&input=LVE=)

---

### Original, 9 bytes

```
4#ô²ìJõ)ò
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NCP0suxK9Sny&input=LVE=)

---

#### Explanation

Using the number Nit found for [his solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164778/58974) (`14425280`) as a starting point, I converted it to base-3, split it to an array of 2 character strings and then tested each permutation to see if any of them produced a perfect square or cube when rejoined to a string and converted back to base-10. That gave me the perfect squares `15366400`, `18011536` & `18421264` and, of those, only `18011536` had a square root that would allow me to save a byte thanks to Japt's trick of using `#` to build numbers, that being `4244`.

```
4#ô           :4244
   ²          :Square
     Jõ       :Array [-1,0,1]
    ì  )      :Convert to a digit array in that base
        ò     :Split on every second element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
([*-1..1]*2).permutation(2).uniq-[[0,0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZqtrV/1fI1pL11BPzzBWy0hTryC1KLe0JLEkMz9PA8gtzcss1I2ONtAxiI39X2tdoJCmp6H5HwA)

Comment: Could you add a TIO link? Also I've never used Ruby yet, but i think this also outputs (0, 0), which isn't a valid step.

Comment: Oh yeah I completely missed the [0, 0]. I adjusted and added a TiO link. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 86 bytes

```
+[[<+>->->>---<<<]>]>---.>.<.>.<-.+.>.-.<-.>.+.<.>..<.+.>..<-.>.<+.>.<-.>.-.<.>.<+.>+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fOzraRttOFwjtdHV1bWxsYu1iQSw9Oz0bENbV0wZSuiCGHZAJEgMS2mAKrEgbogqsBsrX1vv/HwA)

Prints pairs of numbers separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 15 bytes

```
{(+1-!x#3)^,&x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpD21BXsULZWDNOR62i9n@agvF/AA)

```
 x:2 / for testing
 x#3 / that many 3s
3 3
 !x#3 / all vectors of 0 1 2 as the columns of a matrix
(0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2)
 +!x#3 / transpose
(0 0
 0 1
 0 2
 1 0
 1 1
 1 2
 2 0
 2 1
 2 2)
 &x / that many 0s
0 0
 (+!x#3)^,&x / remove the all-zero vector
(0 1
 0 2
 1 0
 1 1
 1 2
 2 0
 2 1
 2 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Print@Rest@Tuples[{0,1,-1},2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCEotbjEIaS0ICe1OLraQMdQR9ewVsco9v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

```javascript
_=>`1,1
1,0
1,-1
0,1
0,-1
-1,1
-1,0
-1,-1`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i7BUMeQy1DHAIh1DbkMdEAYyNAFCeuCxHVBEgn/k/PzivNzUvVy8tM10jQ0Nf8DAA)

## Explanation :

Does nothing basically no input and prints the string separated by new lines using string literal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 24 bytes

```
K`_ _
_
_$"0
+0`_
1$%"-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zshXiGeCwhVlAy4tA0S4rkMVVSVdIEyAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>26</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
9,[4]-{.3/(\3%(n}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31In2iRWt1rPWF8jxlhVI69W//9/AA)

My first GolfScript submission, any help is appreciated! Outputs one element per line, and removes the `0, 0` element.

For nicer printing, I found this 20 byte solution:

```
9,[4]-{[.3/(\3%(]p}%
```

which prints one array per line.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 32 bytes

```
For(A,-1,1
For(B,-1,1
If A≠2B
Disp A,B,"
End
End
```

Prints pairs as two lines, separated by empty lines.

TI-Basic is a [tokenized language](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens), all tokens used here are one-byte.

Explanation:

```
For(A,-1,1 # First number from -1 to 1 (inclusive)
For(B,-1,1 # Second number from -1 to 1 (inclusive)
If A≠2B    # If the pair is not 0,0
Disp A,B," # Print the first number, then the second, then
           # an empty string (each on its own line)
End        # End second number loop
End        # End first number loop
```

Output

```
-1
-1

-1
0

-1
1

0
-1

0
1

1
-1

1
0

1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 49 bytes

An anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=-1To 1
For j=-1To 1
If i Or j?i,j
Next
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHTVtcwJF/BkAvEyYJxPNMUMhX8gQL2mTpZXH6pFSVg4v9/IwXj/wA)

#### Output

```vb
-1 -1
-1 0
-1 1
0 -1
0 1
1 -1
1 0
1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 66 bytes

An anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=-1To 1:For j=-1To 1:?IIf(i Or j,i &" "&j &vbCr,"");:Next j,i
```

#### Output

```vb
-1 -1
-1 0
-1 1
0 -1
0 1
1 -1
1 0
1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
p (w=*-1..1).product(w)-[[0,0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBo9xWS9dQT89QU6@gKD@lNLlEo1xTNzraQMcgNvb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
[(A=[0:3;5:8])%3 A÷3]-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@moWn7P1rD0TbawMrY2tTKIlZT1VjB8fB241hdw/8FRZl5JTl5GkBVmv8B)

Generate `[0,1,2,0,2,0,1,2]` in the first column and `[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2]` in the second (excluding 4%3 and 4÷3 to avoid `0 0`), then subtract 1 from all the values.

Other methods I tried:

`[(i,j)for i=-1:1,j=-1:1 if i|j!=0]`

`[[s...].-'1'for s=base.(3,[0:3;5:8],2)]` (based on Stewie Griffin's Octave solution)

`[(i,j)for i=-1:1,j=-1:1][(1:9).!=5]`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Most browsers), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
for(x=9;x;)--x-4&&alert([~(-x/3),x%3-1])
```

Only works in DevTools in browsers. As per [New users' guides to golfing rules in specific languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/11932#11932) this should be valid (Full browser JS program).

#### If the one above is anyway considered a snippet, then <s>47</s> 45 bytes:

```
_=>{for(x=9;x;)--x-4&&alert([~(-x/3),x%3-1])}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
1╤╫■╞
```

-2 bytes by porting [*@ბიმო*'s second Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164785/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9tYXRoZ29sZv//MeKVpOKVq@KWoOKVnv//)

**Explanation:**

```python
1╤     # Push list [-1,0,1] (push 1; pop and push a list in the range [-n,n])
  ╫    # Rotate it once towards the left: [0,1,-1]
   ■   # Take the cartesian product with itself, creating all possible pairs
    ╞  # Discard the first item of this list (the [0,0] pair)
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
T®šã¨
```

Port of [*@ბიმო*'s second Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164785/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6PBcm8MNhxcfWvb/PwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
T      # Push 10
 ®š    # Prepend -1 as list: [-1,1,0]
   ã   # Take the cartesian product of this list with itself, generating all pairs
    ¨  # Remove the last one, which is the [0,0]
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 219 bytes

```
[S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S T   N
_Push_1][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S T   N
_Push_1][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S S T    N
_Push_1][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S S T    N
_Push_1][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S T   N
_Push_1][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S S T    N
_Push_1][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][S S S T    N
_Push_1][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T S T T   T   S N
_Push_46][T S S S _Add_top_two][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIQnA4FYAQyAMqATG5gGwQ4IKogyjgBCn4/9/I1JTLyBQA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Prints with a `.` delimiter between each number, and `/` between each pair of numbers. Since the codepoints of both `.` and `/` are between `-` and `01`, these are the shortest delimiters to use with this approach.

Uses [this Whitespace tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210) to print the output. The optimal constant `46` is generated by [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fVLJbtswEL3nK4g5kaBFS0B7iGQiSIAeBNQ5VO4CBEFBKYzNVKZUamTAKPztChVJXtoiFw45783jbC9qp4KXp19dV5SqachSGfvnipC6zUtTkAYVerOrzBPZeohm6IxdPzwSxXoaIYODON20JRJJ1EP4mLwhxiJptqosddMDqUW91k4sb3/8/Hb7@eunGUnldXIuMrG/TGIAA/5cOdrLGZkmZhF9DBPD@ZjAKQUJMMNZLaeoIS7foyZ5PCQo1hrvvKOh7BhOCEovvqq@b4xHalXoO2OV2w@6NA8MS45cJykK/btVZUNrdgPZfQYxMu5OlFri9DiM1jxTJ0pt17ihjCyOlZ4l8U/xZ4pnbTzJnODU@83ll8OZ7RvUW1G1KGpfC5aWwhAugU@iHBLfWOApBxIT4O/1ImXjt38r08v031iHK3@MGzTO6D3tfsB2bMhOOT8VyDLg1EoZ3gDEduHNCmLIgF2uRRFPy4XVhWSPsqXCjVB5Qy1j/5s/clksPlz7UXrt1bg7Q/@cxtZZz4B7GCo6dF0XimgeiiCaRyKcB/0Rif7hPUF/C/rrKw).

NOTE: Hard-coded with tab and newline delimiters (since their codepoints are pretty short, being `9` and `10` respectively) [would be **332 bytes** instead](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYuTS4ETSAMxJ4gNApwIQU4FmCAWhZxYFXJiMxKLQk5iFWI3kWi7sbqSk2gzOYk08/9/AA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 238 bytes

```
{iiiii}ddc{d}ddddddc{ii}dddcdddddciiiic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiciiiicdddddciiiiic{dd}iiic{i}iiiiiicddddciciiiic{dd}iiic{i}iiiiiicddddciiiiic{dd}iiic{ii}dddcdddddciiiiic{dd}iiic{i}iiiciiiicdddddciciiiic{dd}iiic{ii}dddcdddddciciiiic{dd}iiic{ii}dddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1RCoAwDENP5KEkUey3n2Vnr6ZjyIosH4XmJYTHztPua4twkxoJ53sleBpE/8Qn2GSk@wWUYILOB4VhSQusu7U4zWJV/ocRDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 39 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 39 bytes.

- Filename: `0 1;0 -1;1 0;-1 0;1 1;1 -1;-1 1;-1 -1.p`
- Content is empty.

How would you do that by control flowing although we don't have negative constants nor the way to obtain negative value without `.i` or `._`!

Comment: Other attempt: `-1 -1;.e.s.p-1 0;.e.s.p-1 1;.e.s.p`, 34 bytes up to six pairs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
1u0W2↔Ṫ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxdTBXMuKGlOG5qiIsIiIsIiJd)

#### Explained

```
1u0W2↔Ṫ
1u0W    # list of [1,-1,0]
    2↔  # combinations of length 2
      Ṫ # remove tail which is [0,0] which is not needed in the challenge
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 44 bytes

```
puts "-1 -1
0 -1
1 -1
-1 0
1 0
-1 1
0 1
1 1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWEFJ11BB15DLAESAWUC@ARcIAxkgcZCwodL//wA)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 77 bytes

```
set j -1
time {set i -2
time {puts [expr [incr i]|$j?"$i $j":""]} 3
incr j} 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIUtB15CrJDM3VaEaxM1U0DWCcgtKS4oVolMrCooUojPzkosUMmNrVLLslVQyFVSylKyUlGJrFYy5wDJZQNb//wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
↘1/⊂⊞⊂.∸~1
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__4oaYMS_iioLiip7iioIu4oi4fjEK)

```
↘1/⊂⊞⊂.∸~1
       ∸~1  # the list [0 ¯1 1]
      .     # duplicate
    ⊞⊂      # cartesian product
  /⊂        # decrement rank
↘1          # drop first row which is [0 0]
```