# Modified Boggle Checker, with Modified Boggle-able Code

Tags: code-challenge, decision-problem

## Background

[Boggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle) is a board game where the players have to find English words on a 4-by-4 board of random alphabets. Words can be constructed by selecting sequentially adjacent cells on the board. ("adjacent" means horizontally, vertically or diagonally adjacent.) Also, same cell can't be used more than once in a word.

The following is an example board:

```
I L A W
B N G E
I U A O
A S R L
```

On this board, `BINGO`, `ORANGE` and `WEARS` are valid words, but `SURGE` and `RUSSIA` are not:

- `SURGE` : There's no adjacent pair on the board having `RG`.
- `RUSSIA` : `S` cannot be used twice.

**Modified Boggle** is a modified version of Boggle, with the following rules:

- The board size is `n`-by-`n`, where `n` can be any positive integer.
- Each cell can contain any one byte between 0 and 255 inclusive.
- A cell can be used more than once, *but not twice in a row*.

Using the example board above, in addition to `BINGO`, `ORANGE` and `WEARS`, `LANGUAGE` becomes a valid string (since `G` is used twice, but not twice in a row) but `RUSSIA` is still not (due to `SS` pair).

Here is another example using a code fragment. The string `from itertools import*\n` can be found on the following board, but not `from itertoosl import*` or `from itertools import *`:

```
f   i   ' ' s
r   t   m   l
e   o   o   p
\n  *   t   r
```

Note that you need two `o`'s in order to match the `oo` sequence.

## Challenge

Write a function or program that, given a Modified Boggle board `B` (of any size) and a string `s`, determines if `s` can be found on `B`.

## Restrictions

**Your code itself should also fit on a Modified Boggle board `b`.** That is, you must show the board `b` in your submission along with your code, so that your function/program outputs true if it is given `b` and your code as input.

## Scoring

**The score of your submission is the side length of the smallest board `b` where you can fit your code.** Ties are broken by the usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules, i.e. the length of your code in bytes. The submission with the **lowest score** (for both criteria) wins.

For example, `from itertools import*\n` has the score of 4 (using the board above) and code length of 23 bytes.

## Input and Output

For input, you can take any convenient method for both `B` and `s`. This includes list of chars and list of charcodes, 2D or flattened or whatever makes sense. Also, you can optionally take the board size as a part of the input.

For output, you can choose one of the following:

- Truthy and falsy values following your language's convention, or
- One predefined value for true and false respectively.

Please specify your input/output method in your submission.

Comment: I suspect some esolang that has a very tiny charset that can fit on a 2x2 will win xD

Comment: And any [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) program is going to score 4 but is almost guaranteed to lose because of the tie rule against a language efficiently using 4 distinct symbols.

Comment: @Arnauld I was thinking maybe [tinyBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TinyBF) and when you need two adjacent symbols you just do a `+=+=` or something like that. The problem is the `==` output function...

Comment: If it wasn't a standard loophole, you create a pseudolanguage by encoding an existing language in a fixed-width base 3 encoding, and then mapping each base 3 digit to a horizontal, diagonal or vertical move on the 2x2 board.

Comment: Fair warning: The fact that the board can contain a null byte will make it a lot harder for brainfuck (and derivatives), as well as a few other esolangs

Comment: What do "twice in a row" mean?

Comment: @l4m2 You can't "stand still" on the same cell, say `S`, to match `SS` in `RUSSIA`.

Comment: winner will of course be some base-2 or base-3 language?

Comment: http://esolangs.org/wiki/Binaryfuck

Comment: @l4m2 Solving with such a language is always welcome, but beware Jo King's warning above.

Comment: Is this really [tag:restricted-source]? I think it's just a two-fold challenge (more for non-golfing languages), where you're supposed to find both code and the smallest possible Boggle board in which the code fits.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I added it when the challenge asked for fitting the code into 4x4 board (while in the sandbox). Removed the tag as it's no longer the case now.

Comment: A solution in BF is almost guaranteed to score 3 if you could solve it.

Comment: Do we have a tag for "fewest unique characters" challenges?

Comment: @mbomb007 you of course can solve it with a length input or some encoded symbol

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, score 3, 20972 bytes

```
exec'cecxc%c'%(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+…
```

Full code is the output of: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBbtswDD3HX8FpCCTNnpH0GMQFvGEoCmQdMKPYIfNBU9RUmyMLthsk@/mMpGtgqQ8SST@Sj4@K5@G5DTcX2@4cFCCE@Hmxzp5sYcI5sRnahQ/xZVA6sSd0GheURduxYw6/dmaGcATSQfgVmetCyrajP1sM1VtbFwXFt4v6drHmDoprqCl5u1zVGTrknhCgn8b8k515bPlR2duFpg6pSpepXRMbPYHcCHIEcyPQMZkR7Ca4f1L/t3hXKEZpGs4WnQl7pxiZxM6HYXZF9LUmZ0/8HNMjCrORipt8fUEx864fOh9RvOQ9fEaN9y4AAsGAfTadsYPr8mSPyo9Sgl2BkHMr50pACjKV@e8WJ5NL@aHtdqi8xrDQgup9NX8cFgrGHx30bfMy@DbkeZ5UtEnifFXjYKLaZ7RozXTKGJsz5h0ctHHwB//XUIE@T4jgEXzAXBYP6ALWAnBCOqk6sIjAglKcw@wDxwE797Hx@HZWCeBHvKq8c7Ex1qk3xOCodUbD91LMjzq5BgtEkywCIXzzCMyiQoO3BfQ2q9fVQXXZyvtN@UNm8tPD3Re87h/Lb3iV1feNrDOQm/Lh7rHEX/8A)

Fits on the Boggle board:

```
e x (
c % 1
' + )
```

Decodes and executes this program:

```
cecxc=any
c,cec=input()
cxec=len(c)
cexec=lambda    cxc,cexc,c,cec:cexc<=''or   cxc[cec][c]==cexc[0]>0<cecxc(cexec(cxc,cexc[1:],cxcxc,cxcec)for cxcxc   in(c-(c>0),c,c+(+1+c<cxec))for  cxcec   in(cec-(cec>0),cec,cec+(+1+cec<cxec))if(cxcxc,cxcec)!=(c,cec))
cxc=range(cxec)
print   cecxc(cexec(c,cec,cexc,cxec)for cexc    in  cxc for cxec    in  cxc)
```

Which takes input like: `['ILAW','BNGE','IUAO','ASRL'], 'LANGUAGE'`

Comment: Hm, looks like [I've found a way](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165169/41024) to do that in Jelly.

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), score 2, 9351 bytes

```
'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))~))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))~'))))))))))))))))))')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))')))'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))~'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))~'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VmxCgMhDN37FcVF7jNSOORArtBydCgdSrdCf8FftzcUOisx9@LFxcnkvZgXo77ez0/OfviNNAiObby2wdGQS51pWFIsRiFSRwYEeHYq3FYdEYUJKCvV5sVMrDL0U4Lgzq4tXCgRNIQc8diY6jGZIKpKjdJ5PQhlLtCdoXRVJ4qAlASoCxMF6IFX43a3JxpqFyOYO5WuQJppNhx4Txv23IeNg5sVSJQKYSh5ZO02/lph2x5qLC96vztbIscNrfwPqN16rDeyTmknnVLRSJ7L0n@tb0MwabOb891N8Ubu6E5zGNdpWui8TnS9RPc4RJrDQmH8Ag) Expects input like:

```
["ILWA" "BNGE" "IUAO" "ASRL"]
LANGUAGE
```

and fits on the Boggle board:

```
' )
~ )
```

Constructs the string `l~:Q,:K;{\:Y;\:X;:C,!_{;QY=X=C0==_{;[X(XX)]K,&[Y(YY)]K,&m*[XY]a-C1>:D;{~DF}%:|}&}|}:F;l:R;K,2m*{~RF}%:|~` then evaluates it as CJam code.

Comment: Unless a built-in exists somewhere (I'm looking at you, Mathematica), a score of 2 is the lowest you can get. So now the challenge is to make a shorter version of the same size.

Comment: @EngineerToast Not just any built-in. It has to be a 1-byte built-in, because you cannot use the same boggle space more than once in a row.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's exactly what I meant but I did not explicitly say so. The clarification rules out languages like Unary or anything else that's just the same character repeated.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl), score 12 (175 bytes)

<sup>(This is almost certainly going to be outgolfed by an esolang and probably normal languages as well.)</sup>

```
import StdEnv;>[]_ _ _ _=True;>[c:s]i j n a=i<n&&j<n&&i>=0&&j>=0&&a.[i,j]==c&&or[>s k l n a\\k<-[i-1..i+1],l<-[j-1..j+1]|i<>k||j<>l];$n c a=or[>c i j n a\\i<-[0..n],j<-[0..n]]
```

This defines a function `$ :: Int [Char] {#String} -> Bool` which checks whether the second argument (the word) can be found in the third argument (the board) given the first argument as width.

In the board on which this fits (see below), `*` marks unused places. There are 16 of those, on a board of size 12×12 = 144, meaning 128 are used effectively (an **efficiency** of **175/128 ≈ 1.37**). It may be possible to get the same program on 11×11, but this is all done by hand and very tedious; my boss probably wouldn't be happy if I would try to get it on 11×11.

```
* * & & * * * * * * * ;
s [ n < j * * u r T > v
  > r & i > * e =   [ n
l k o & 0 = n   ; _ ] E
  & a . = ] a j i > [ d
a n & c [ j . + ] s c t
\ k < - i , - . 1 | : S
\ * 1 l . + 1 = i j |  
[ i \ . , ] o a < > k t
0 - < \ a   r >   l ] r
. j , * n j [ i c $ ; o
. n ] ] * *     n i m p
```

[Try it online (with the program itself as input)!](https://tio.run/##tZHBjtsgEIbP9VOMspEjEZuNe1wbn7qHSr0lNxutWEyzYAxZIJFWdV@9LiG7PfVWFaTRzKcZ4P/hWjCzTHY4awETk2aR08m6APswPJpL3Xb0CdImB3cWseYPnkpQYIAR2Zg8V9cgW7KLaYoMd7JQlBCe59Z1rYcR9LW/78em7GRZYSy3FS10rNS1UrGaZdOO86yaVtN6bYDH86/THN5v63sZ@3cYG1qoj4wu@8DicwmsofoMJ2ePjk3wbJkbsuz@Hg4vAjybBHA7CGAe2LO9iOyjkUC3@a@K/1Xz31Vv6B9xSWoNxgYB4YUF6MGJ17N0woPwnJ2kORbgLcgAgxXebAJoa8folQjhLUvz0Ycfd9mnFUJ5jm6rXhUR@M40CqGzO7SXBKB1UToS0TiTgB5tviMG6if6eOuIdhDKlGy7IQFmct4pvKWehwSSJ7IocTU/7N8JqjTeVkSqGRLpZN/jgloWHbpN7cqm7xm4FjR1iWBVIKM6yde1vYFoDUIAJn7p6me2/OLfNTv6pfz6bfnyZtgkuf8N)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, score 23, <s>538</s> 507 bytes

<sup>NSFW</sup>

```
import java.util.function.*;import java.util.stream.*;class B{static BiFunction<char[][],String,BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Byte>>f;{f=(b,s)->(i,j)->{try{if(b[i][j]!=s.charAt(0))return 0;}catch(Exception e){return 0;}if(s.length()<2)return 1;byte t=0;for(int k=9;k-->1;){t|=f.apply(b,s.substring(1)).apply(i+~k%3+1,j+~(k/3)%3+1);}return t;};BiFunction<char[][],String,Byte>g=(b,s)->{int l=b.length;return (byte)IntStream.range(0,l*l).map(i->f.apply(b,s).apply(i%l,i/l)).reduce((x,y)->x+y-x*y).getAsInt();};}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVLBjtsgEL3vV9CVVoYEs0n3VLG2tJZaqeccrRywgx1sQiwYb2NR76@nOOtkV6rUW5HQAE/z3pthGvEq4mbXns/q0B0toCY8sB6UZlVvSlBHwxb8L8yBleIQkFIL51DmHQhQJcrUjznrudwLm2/zLd2AVaamn6CfBmQtLb3GbACZphX3VYIL6kicYkWbEDzYwasKF7na5s32S@LYRPsCeEWIldBbg1Z8LAWUe/z9VMpu4keS@A8wpDumpalhj8nz12vamhdBFUGy4tXRYmUAtck33sZxuubEw@@kYqLr9DA5Yq4v3KUMvCZkflfLt/bhabmmzfINt49PZLoQPs4CwEf@r3ZMNdfXev2kr5NiNspnDjx5JKFNm/d@W2FqiVdULzRhB9FhFaefbN6cPWiqHnVwauWuLyXGJzoEldNyiE@LgbBawosLtDjY5Wc0r83gQB7YsQfWBY@gDa5nRiN/oWsF3kcuopEIW0Yj9VERTibs9nIrw6m84ONI0b0zopX3hPC7/ysTxvCmMt5dQtcXOszkPJqvR7VDB6EMfv@BfIuErR1B/uYsQwVK0GQiwzeq8fwH)

Compiled with JDK 9, but should work with 8.

I didn't know what to do with the imports and static field (which is in fact necessary), so I decided to just take the whole class and stick the lambdas in a initializer.
The lambda `g` can then be applied on a 2D array and a string, and returns `1` if the string is in the board and `0` if not (as a `Byte`, 3 characters shorter than `Integer`).

Credit to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164762) guy for a (in my case) shorter than hardcoding way to address neighbouring cells.

Somewhere in the progress of making this monstrosity I got invested in making it work with lambdas it got progressively worse and worse until this happened. It doesn't even get close to the other answers and it is probably not even close to the optimal solution in Java, but hey, it fits pretty neatly on a 23x23 board (which is not optimal, but perhaps closer than the program itself):

```
duce((x,y)->x+y-x*y).ge
e l=b.length;return (bt
rt3+1,j+~(k/3)%3+1);}yA
.n%te t=0;for(int k=rts
)iky0;}catchExcepti9e)I
){~b (b,s)->(i,j)-o;tIn
l>+;n=ring,iFunct>nkunt
/-i1rftass B{stai{ -rt(
i)( u{Slport jatote-nS)
,synt;,cmutil.vinr)> t;
l,lref];i.porfac<y{1tr}
%bpur>[*;amitu. I{r;}e;
i(pt)>].*vaj nuBnie);a}
y=ae)e[m.noitctitft{Bm}
lg.r0traerts.liFe(uti.}
p>))(yhc<noitcnugbr|Fr 
pe12tB,regetnI,re[n=ua 
at(<Arahc.s=!]j[]i fng 
.yg)(htgnel.s(fi};0.ce 
)Bnirtsbus.s,b(ylppat( 
s,gnirtS,][][rahc<noi0 
,b(ylppa.f>-i(pm.)l*l,
```

Of course, at that point there was no point in trying to make that by hand. So as a bonus, here's the (naive) function I used to compress the code onto the board:

```
static char[][] toBoggleBoard(String s, int n) {

    char[][] board = new char[n][n];
    int i = n / 2;
    int j = i;
    int[] d = {1, 0};

    s = s + s.charAt(s.length() - 1); //the last char gets eaten don't ask me why PS editing loop condition does make it work but causes a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    board[i][j] = s.charAt(0);
    s = s.substring(1);
    while (s.length() > 0)
    {
        int[] ra = add(d, right(d));
        int[] r = right(d);
        int[] l = left(d);

        if (board[i + d[0]][j + d[1]] > 0)
        {
            if (board[i + d[0]][j + d[1]] == s.charAt(0))
            {
                i += d[0];
                j += d[1];
                s = s.substring(1);
            }
            else
            {
                i += l[0];
                j += l[1];
                board[i][j] = s.charAt(0);
                s = s.substring(1);
            }
        }
        else if (board[i + ra[0]][j + ra[1]] == s.charAt(0))
        {
            i += ra[0];
            j += ra[1];
            s = s.substring(1);
        }
        else if (board[i + r[0]][j + r[1]] > 0)
        {
            i += d[0];
            j += d[1];
            board[i][j] = s.charAt(0);
            s = s.substring(1);
        }
        else
        {
            int[] rb = sub(r, d);
            d = r;
            if (board[i + rb[0]][j + rb[1]] > 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                i += d[0];
                j += d[1];
                board[i][j] = s.charAt(0);
                s = s.substring(1);
            }   
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < board.length; ++k)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < board.length; ++l)
        {
            if (board[k][l] == 0)
            {
                board[k][l] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    return board;
}

static int[] left(int[] d) {
    return new int[]{-d[1], d[0]};
}

static int[] right(int[] d) {
    return new int[]{d[1], -d[0]};
}

static int[] add(int[] x, int[] y) {
    return new int[]{x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]};
}

static int[] sub(int[] x, int[] y) {
    return new int[]{x[0] - y[0], x[1] - y[1]};
}
```

It maps it's input onto a spiral<sup>the snaking implementation didn't work</sup>, leaving characters out if possible. It's rather simple so could probably be improved and I forgot to add checking for characters in the backwards-right direction<sup>(update: I added it an it produced incorrect results)</sup>, so I could probably shave off one or two characters but I doubt it's getting on a 22x22.

Edit:
Removed 6 spaces in places they didn't need to be.
Saved 13 bytes by replacing a check on array indices with a try-catch.
Shaved off 12 bytes by moving the board size into an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2316 bytes, score 3

```
1111111111111111111111111111111,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,11111111111111111111,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111111111,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111D§ịØJv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98QP9AxHJ5AZ5g4S2dweE5nNI0MP3fpDBG/64wm1mHhT52h4jSd0VAdZk5yObT84e7uwzO8yv4fbj866eHOGf//R0erp2UqFKvrKKgXleTmgOjU/PwCEB2Tp1VSpB4LZKUV5ecqZJakFpXk5@cUK2TmFuQXlWipxwIA)

Board:

```
1,v
D1J
§ịØ
```

Note: this is a (somewhat) trivial solution. Credit to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn) for the [idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165171/41024).

Returns a non-empty list if `s` can be found in `B`, and an empty list if not. The added footer helps clarifying that.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was allowed. I wanted to return 0 if `s` could not be found, or a positive integer if it could be found. But the rules state "One predefined value for true and false respectively". Or are empty/non-empty for false/true convention in Jelly?

Comment: @Keelan Jelly's "if-like" construct, which, by default, defines truthiness of a value, will consider an empty list to be falsy and any other list to be truthy. It's really just Python 3's convention (since that's what Jelly is implemented in).