# Your Memory's Leaking

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to write a program that:

- Runs indefinitely
- Produces no output
- Consumes an unbounded amount of memory

### Specifications

- You must list the implementation used for your program. This is relevant because some implementations might preform optimizations while others do not. For example, the LISP code `(defun f () (f)) (f)` may or may not consume infinite memory depending on whether the implementation optimizes tail recursion.
- Obviously, your program may terminate from running out of memory.

### Examples

BF:

```
+[>+]
```

Python:

```
l = []
while True:
    l.append(1)
```

JavaScript:

```
l = [];
while (true)
    l.push(1);
```

C (I'm not sure if this works):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    while (1)
        malloc(1);
}
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid solution (in bytes) wins.

Comment: A dup of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101709/shortest-program-that-continuously-allocates-memory/101834#101834

Comment: Depending on how strictly you interpret things: if a C compiler can prove that code has no effect, it can replace it with anything else that also has no effect. So given an arbitrarily smart compiler, it might not be possible to write an infinite C program with no effect. In practice this is hampered by the fact that none of our compilers can solve the halting problem. Also, `malloc` is in `stdlib.h`, not `stdio.h`.

Comment: @ephemient That's why I forced you to specify the implementation. Also, some compilers will already include `<stdlib.h>` by default.

Comment: Some compilers will happen to pull in `stdlib.h` transitively via `stdio.h`. That doesn't mean they include `stdlib.h` by default.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
‘ß
```

Increments and calls itself recursively. As the integer gets bigger, more memory is required to store it.

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYcbh@f//AwA), but it's not much to look at.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause stack overflow before your computer runs out of memory?

Comment: No, Jelly has tail call optimization. This is just a fancy while loop.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 16 bytes

```
i=9
while i:i*=9
```

As `int`s in Python3 are only limited by the memory, this will run until there is no more memory available.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 15 bytes

```
i=[];loop{i<<0}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-98, 1 byte

```
'
```

Fills the stack with strings containing `'`

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 75 bytes

```java
interface G{static void main(String[]a){a=new String[1];for(;;)a[0]+=' ';}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#@5@ZV5JalJaYnKrgXl1ckliSmaxQlp@ZopCbmJmnEVxSlJmXHh2bqFmdaJuXWq4AFTCMtU7LL9KwttZMjDaI1bZVV1C3rq39/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 13 bytes

```
qqaa<esc>"Ax@qq@q
```

This defines a macro, `q` that appends the letter `a` to the register `A` and then calls itself. This results in an infinite loop of making register `A` bigger and bigger, only limited by memory.

Comment: It looks to me like you're missing an `<esc>` in the macro. This will just output `a"Ax@qq@q` and exit.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 8 bytes

```
(()){()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hoalZraFZ@/8/AA)

Comment: Since the `{...}` monad keeps track of the value of each run, you could simply do `(()){[]}` or `(()){()}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 17 bytes

```bash
for((;;)){ a+=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6ShYW2tqVmtkKhtm2hd@/8/AA)